# Programmatically Trigger Kendo Chart.seriesClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

This is a pretty small and simple question.  Looking online I wasn't able to find anything but I would like to be able to unit test our kendo chart and specifically that the seriesClick event works as expected.  Problem is I can't seem to find a way to trigger the event.  I am trying to target the chart series via jQuery and call .click().  Trying this approach gave me nothing so in a moment of desparation I tried clicking everything

```
$('*').each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

With no such luck.  Here is the chartOptions snippet

```
$scope.chartOptions = {
                //...
                // On Click add the criteria to the serach bar.
                seriesClick: function (series) {
                        console.log("seriesClick");
                        //Do stuff here                            
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            };
```

I don't get the console output when I try running the above mentioned jQuery code in my unit test.  Here it is.

```
xit('should update the searchbar when a series item has been clicked', inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        //Write out the directive
        //We have a directive that will replace this tag with the kendo-chart directive
        var ele = $compile('<chart></chart>')(scope); 
        angular.element(document.body).append(ele);
        scope.$digest();
        $timeout.flush(0);
        scope = ele.isolateScope();

        console.log('clicking everything');
        $('*').each(function () {
            $(this).click();
        });
```

I've submitted the same question to the telerik forums hoping to get some advice from the "experts" but I don't get a response nearly as fast as SO.

**EDIT**
I did run across this [post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/programmatically-trigger-legenditemclick-event) in the Telerik forums and am hoping that what I need to do is not "currently not supported out of the box".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking on the [telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/programatically-trigger-seriesclick) I finally came down to the this answer

```
 element.mousedown().mouseup()    //Trigger events for Chrome, Firefox and IE9
            .trigger(jQuery.Event("MSPointerDown", { originalEvent: {} })).trigger(jQuery.Event("MSPointerUp", { originalEvent: {} }))  //Trigger event for IE10
            .trigger(jQuery.Event("pointerdown", { originalEvent: {} })).trigger(jQuery.Event("pointerup", { originalEvent: {} })); //Trigger event for IE11
```

Apparently it listens for the mousedown() mouseup() events.  And then after seeing it didnt' work for IE10 and 11 I needed to use another way of triggering mousedown()/mouseup()

Comment: hello 
I'm trying to implement a function to the click when the legend is triggered click on the series, except as described unable miss something?

Comment: You may want to ask your own question.  I don't totally understand the question though so you might want to clarify.  Feel free to refer to this post in your question to help others zero in to your thought process.